# Erro ao instalar o Composer no Projeto em Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, composer

Estou iniciando no mundo Laravel e estou com um problema no rodar o `composer install` no projeto. Ao rodar o comando, mostra o seguinte erro:

```
D:\htdocs\cpi2>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zizaco/confide dev-master requires laravelbook/ardent 2.4.x -> satisfiable
 by laravelbook/ardent[v2.4.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation 4.2.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA4|install illuminat
e/support v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA3|install illuminat
e/support v4.1.10|install illuminate/support v4.1.11|install illuminate/support
v4.1.6|install illuminate/support v4.1.7|install illuminate/support v4.1.8|insta
ll illuminate/support v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.12
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal 2.4.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9|install illuminate/supp
ort v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8|install illuminate/supp
ort v4.1.0|install illuminate/support v4.1.1|install illuminate/support v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal v2.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal v2.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev|install laravel/fram
ework 4.1.x-dev|install illuminate/support v4.1.0|install illuminate/support v4.
1.1|install illuminate/support v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.10|install laravel/fr
amework 4.1.x-dev|install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev|install illuminate/support
 v4.1.0|install illuminate/support v4.1.1|install illuminate/support v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.12
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal v2.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal 2.4.0-RC2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal 2.4.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal 2.4.0-BETA2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.1|install laravel/framewo
rk 4.1.x-dev|install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev|install laravel/framework v4.1.
10|install laravel/framework v4.1.11|install laravel/framework v4.1.12|install l
aravel/framework v4.1.9|install illuminate/validation v4.1.10|install illuminate
/validation v4.1.11|install illuminate/validation v4.1.8|install illuminate/vali
dation v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.7
    - laravel/framework v4.0.0 requires doctrine/dbal 2.4.x -> satisfiable by do
ctrine/dbal[2.4.0-BETA1, 2.4.0-BETA2, 2.4.0-RC1, 2.4.0-RC2, 2.4.x-dev, v2.4.0, v
2.4.1, v2.4.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/dbal 2.4.0-BETA1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.3|install laravel/framewo
rk v4.1.3|install laravel/framework v4.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.2
    - Installation request for zizaco/confide dev-master -> satisfiable by zizac
o/confide[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.2|install laravel/framewo
rk v4.1.2|install laravel/framework v4.1.3
    - laravelbook/ardent v2.4.0 requires illuminate/validation ~4.1 -> satisfiab
le by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11,
v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illumi
nate/validation[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12,
 v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.1, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework
 v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework
 v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework
 v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework
 v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework
 v4.0.0-BETA2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel
/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1,
v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
```

Isto se deve por causa do projeto ser em Laravel 4 e na hora de buscar as dependências ta buscando do 4.1?

Segue meu `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "leonelsr/cpi2",
    "description": "Comprei Por Impulso 2.0",
    "keywords": ["cpi2", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "zizaco/confide": "dev-master",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
        "robclancy/presenter": "1.0.*",
        "j20/php-uuid": "dev-master",
        "bllim/datatables": "*",
        "orchestra/translation": "2.1.*",
        "baum/baum": "~1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "summerstreet/woodling": "0.1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "dev-master",
        "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master",
        "lmammino/jsmin4assetic": "1.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/library"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Quando acontece isso, eu geralmente instalo somente o framework (laravel/framework), e após instalado, eu começo a adicionar os packages de terceiros, um a um, assim fica mais fácil conseguir instalar tudo :-)

Answer (score 5):

Mude isso:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
```

Para:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
```

O Ardent precisa da versão 4.1.

Comment: Mudei mas o problema persiste.

Answer (score 2):

Não adianta mudar para `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"` já tive este problema, você tem ter a versão 4.1 e instalar o Ardent também como pedi aqui

```json
Problem 1
    - zizaco/confide dev-master requires laravelbook/ardent 2.4.x -> satisfiable
```

Answer (score 2):

Apenas corrija o seu **composer.json** para:

```json
{
   ...
   ...
    "require": {
       "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
       ...
       ...
       ...
        "zizaco/confide": "3.1.x",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master"
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Recomendo fazer uma nova instalação para evitar problemas com dependências. (Caso seja possível).

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais fácil de resolver isto e baixar a versão 4 direto, ao tentar instalar pelo `composer` ele esta tentando achar a ultima versão dos arquivos.

Link para a [4.0.9](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/v4.0.9.zip)

Posterior descompacte no diretório que deseja instalar o laravel e com o composer no diretório execute:

```
php composer install
```

Este ultimo comando ira instalar o laravel, porem e sempre aconselhavel utilizar da ultima versão que pode ser baixado como a branche master:

Link para a [4.1](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip)

O resto do processo utilizando o `composer` é o mesmo do anterior.

Answer (score 0):

pela falta de atualizações do Ardent, é necessário inserir isso em seu **composer.json** para evitar conflitos:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Zizaco/ardent.git"
    }
],
"require": {
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-has-session-fix"
},
```

após isso, rode o **composer update** e provavelmente já estará tudo resolvido

Answer (score -1):

Remova o bloco de código a seguir do seu **composer.json**.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

...isso irá resolver 99% dos problemas da sua vida! :D

Comment: Isso é como varrer a sujeira para debaixo do tapete.

Comment: ... essa dica peguei de um dos desenvolvedores Laravel. Não lembro o link, mas de fato resolveu muito problema pra mim.